# Error when trying to install ubuntu server

Tags: server, system-installation, usb, 16.04, toshiba-satellite

When I try to run the Ubuntu Server 16.04 installer on my USB drive I can get through the language and keyboard dialogues until it says

> Error while running 'modprobe -v usb-storage'.

When I hit continue it gives me a light blue screen with a non-functional command line with a black strip at the very bottom.  I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit this window but get returned to the error window.

If I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and wait 30 sec then I get a window saying:

> Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. This probably means that the CD-ROM was not in the drive. If so you can insert it and try again.  Retry mounting the CD-ROM?

If I hit 'yes' then it takes me back to the error screen.  If I hit 'no' then it takes me to the installation main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Ubuntu Mini](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) instead. It also gives access to a CLI-only installation, which is exactly what I was looking for when I installed it.

Comment: But if I'm mistaken this is ubuntu desktop not server

Comment: I do believe it is server. Especially if you choose to install the command line instead of the full OS.

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: @jpber It will have [some issues](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797855/everything-is-permission-denied), but once those are fixed you'll be good to go.

Comment: @Dev I have never gotten that type of error (that you refer to in your link) on any of my Ubuntu Mini installations; please do not assume that your problems are universal to all users.

Comment: Ok I tried it and was confronted by what looks like a uefi problem and I don't know how to get to legacy mode because I have the new toshiba uefi menu without the option to change the boot mode.

Comment: Oh. I unfortunately don't know how to fix that. Sorry.