# Everything is permission denied

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sudo, ubuntu-minimal

After a fresh [Ubuntu Mini](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) CLI install, nothing has permission to do anything. `ssh-keygen` can't create a directory for `id_rsa.pub`, `git` can't do anything without sudo, etc.

I can read most files, but making directories and reading to some files requires `sudo`.

How do I fix this?

Edit: I think it helps to mention I'm using the default admin account created by the command line installer.

Comment: Please, paste the output of: `whoami && ls -ld $HOME`

Comment: dr-x------ 4 logandark logandark 4096 Jul 12 09:23 /home/logandark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions on your $HOME directory are incorrect. You can fix it by typing `chmod u+w $HOME`.

Notice that the files and directories you created using `sudo` are probably owned by root now, so, you will need to fix ownership on these. You can do it by using `sudo chown logandark.logandark <file or directory name>`.

**EDIT:** To change ownership recursivelly, add the `-R` option to `chown`, like `chown -R logandark.logandark .git`. Be very careful when doing stuff recursivelly.

Comment: After using `sudo chown logandark.logandark -R $HOME` I still can't use `git fetch`

Comment: Actually, forgot the `-R`.